# Android - Getting error while accessing location service

Tags: android, location

I am getting error while accessing location on a Nexus 7 device. The log shows following lines. it was working fine yesterday. What could be wrong?

```
03-06 16:26:36.571      517-769/? E/LocSvc_api_v02﹕ E/locClientSendReq:2092]: invalid handle
03-06 16:26:36.571      517-769/? E/LocSvc_adapter﹕ E/virtual loc_api_adapter_err LocApiV02Adapter::startFix():275]: set opertion mode failed status = eLOC_CLIENT_FAILURE_INVALID_HANDLE, ind..status =
03-06 16:26:36.571      517-769/? E/LocSvc_api_v02﹕ E/locClientSendReq:2092]: invalid handle
03-06 16:26:36.571      517-769/? E/LocSvc_adapter﹕ E/virtual loc_api_adapter_err LocApiV02Adapter::startFix():275]: set opertion mode failed status = eLOC_CLIENT_FAILURE_INVALID_HANDLE, ind..status =
```

My code:

```
locManager =  (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
locManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 10, 10000,this);
Location loc  = locManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
if (loc != null)
{
    Log.v("Latitude", Double.toString(loc.getLatitude()));
    Log.v("Longitude", Double.toString(loc.getLongitude()));
    lastKnownLocation[0] = loc.getLatitude();
    lastKnownLocation[1] = loc.getLongitude();
}
```

Comment: Which line is causing the error? the one that constructs locManager, loc or requests the updates? Working yesterday? do you have intermittent GPS signal? I know my gen 1 nexus7 is a dog in that regard

Comment: Location loc  = locManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
is returning null. Samsung tablet is returning location. I did restart. looking google maps app showing current location.

Comment: changed locManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER) and started working now.

Comment: yep! you just aren't near a window =p